# Smarty in_array value

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

I have array like this

```
{
     "sCode":"05",
     "sCodeName":"critical_tight_connection",
     "iSeverity":1,
     "aData":{
         "iLevelOfDetailt":2,
         "iDuration":35,
         "sLabel":"Labai trumpas pers\u0117dimas, 35 min.",
         "sLink":""
     }
}
```

i am printing him with smarty (array is not serialized, i ve did it for your сonveniece)

```
{if !empty( $aSegment.aNotices.aStop )}
    <ul>
        {foreach from=$aSegment.aNotices.aStop item=aNotice}
            <li>
                <img class="{$aNotice.sCodeName}" />
                {$aNotice.sLabel}
            </li>
        {/foreach}
    </ul>
{/if}
```

how to check with smarty if '05' is exist in aNotices.aStop.sCode ? (before foreach cycle)

Tried this

```
{if in_array('05', $aSegment.aNotices.aStop)}
    exist
{/if}
```

Comment: Maybe `{php}` and `{/php}` around the if statement helps.

Comment: @Bondye no, that is not right.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

you can use this :

```
{if '05'|in_array:$aSegment.aNotices.aStop}EXIST{/if}
```

Comment: Worked like charm  `{if $smarty.session.user.group|in_array:['admin','broker']}`

Comment: how to ignore the case.?

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like this?

```
{if $aNotice.sCode == '05'} ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you **hek2mgl** and **Jeff Bic**, modified your answers and this works fine :

```
{if !$aSegment.aNotices.aStop|@count gt 0}
    {t lang='en'}Stop duration{/t}{if $server.lang != 'en'} / {t}Stop duration{/t}{/if}: {$aSector.aStops.$iSegmentIndex|mins_to_time}
{/if}
```